# Is there any event listener/callback for file download in CollectionFS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, gridfs, collectionfs

I'm using the [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) to store and download files from my application

```
<a href="{{this.url download=true}}">Download</a>
```

And I want to execute a server-side function when the file is downloaded (without using jQuery because it's not really credible and can be bypassed).

I was wondering if there's any undocumented function / workaround to execute my code/hook when there's a download, something like this:

```
filesCollection.on('download', function(fileObject){
  // do stuff
});
```

Thanks

Comment: If `filesCollection` is a Mongo collection, you can use this package to add before/after hooks: https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a *transformRead* in CollectionFS. It's the mirror function of *transformWrite*. [Documentation](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#transformwrite--transformread).